# Transparency/Ambient Occlusion problem

Tags: transparency, ambient-occlusion

I'm working on an architecture visualisation. I'm using the Ambient Occlusion Node for the wall materials. Grass is growing in front of the wall. Grass material is a texture on a transparent plane. The transparent plane of the grass triggers the AO-node, which causes undesired shadows. Grass is casting shadows correctly, Transparent Shadows is checked in Settings/Surface of grass material. Experimented with Light Path, no succsses. See pictures. Any ideas - couldn't find info so far.[image: AOproblem][image: material grass][image: material wall]